# Microsoft Dynamics Nav API Error: Customer Posting Group must have a value in Customer

Tags: php, api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I have some trouble with API method for posting order info into 'API for Dynamics 365 Business Central'.

So in official [doc about order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/fin-graph/api/dynamics_create_salesorder) says for create order you must add 'Customer Info' to the request body. Before that you must create Customer([doc for customer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/fin-graph/api/dynamics_create_customer)).

But if i try to create order with info from Customer request, i have error:

> Error: "Application_FieldValidationException","message":"Customer Posting Group must have a value in Customer"

So main question is: **How to create(or get) and set Posting Group into Customer request?**

Or if it wrong way, how to do this right?

Comment: I’d assume that there should be a default value for posting group somewhere in the setups. Sales & Receivables setup maybe.

Comment: @MakSim, Okay, maybe it's a solution, but how it set via API? Main idea - create customers "in-time".

Comment: Assumption again, APIs are designed in the way that no external system needs to be aware of the posting policy (posting groups etc). So you need to set defaults and create customers with them.

Comment: @MakSim Okay, so do you know how to set default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a **codeunit** that creates the customer by passing some parameters to this codeunit, but if you use a POST to the customer API you cannot call the setup in the body. The request body needs the JSON object.

**You can't create customer ready for posting via API.**
Creating a customer ready for posting (with all posting setup) is something that should do by an interanl user (administrative/financial department) and not by an API.

The API can create the basic customer card, but posting groups and so on could depend on different administrative parameters that you could not always know.